# Reordering WP_Query Result

Tags: wordpress

I have a page in WP that has a grid of content items like the example below

[Grid Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exjeX.jpg)

My site has two content types. I want content type A to show in positions 1, 2, 3, 5 and content type B in 4, 6.  I currently have a query that returns all posts (type A and Type B) and sets the order to random.

My initial thought was to check the posts array to see if type B was not in position 4 & 6 and rerun the loop if necessary, but that doesn't seem like the correct approach.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the query by specific posts such as

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Of course this is only assuming that you already know what posts you want displayed and are not planning to put more specific posts up.

Comment: I assume those are post IDs?

I was able to determine the order or the results that I'm getting from the query.  For example.

(type A, type A, type B, type A, etc.)

What I want to do now is to reorder the array if type B is the 3rd item in the array.